# Change Time zone in pure ruby (not rails)

Tags: ruby, time, timezone, sinatra

I am building a Sinatra site which has mixed UTC/PST data sources, but will be viewed in PST. So I need a way to easily convert Time objects from UTC to PST. 
Without Rails, I don't have access to `Time.zone`, `in_time_zone`, etc.

I only need to change the timezone of a Time object, E.g. `2014-08-14 21:44:17 +0000 => 2014-08-14 14:44:17 -0700.`

First I tried this:

```
class Time
  def to_pst
    self.utc + Time.zone_offset('PDT')
  end
end
```

But this changes the actual timestamps and not the zone. I need both `time.to_i` and `time.strftime` to work; so I can't change the absolute value of the timestamps.

```
> t = Time.now
=> 2014-08-14 21:46:20 +0000
> t.to_pst
=> 2014-08-14 14:46:20 UTC
> t.to_i
=> 1408052780
> t.to_pst.to_i
=> 1408027580
```

[gem 'timezone'](https://rubygems.org/gems/timezone) presents a similar problem.

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Time/Converttimetotimezone.htm) solution works but alters global variables and is not thread-safe.

The OS time zone needs to stay UTC.

I simply need a way to change the Time zone on a single Time object. This is a simple problem and it seems like it should have a simple solution! Has anyone found one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using the [TZInfo gem](http://tzinfo.github.io/).   Also, you should be using the full IANA time zone identifier `'America/Los_Angeles'`.  Time zone abbreviations can be ambiguous (for example, CST has 5 different meanings).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Time` extensions from Active Support outside of Rails:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time'

t = Time.now
#=> 2014-08-15 15:38:56 +0200

t.in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
#=> Fri, 15 Aug 2014 06:38:56 PDT -07:00
```

Now you can do

```
class Time
  def to_pst
    in_time_zone('Pacific Time (US & Canada)')
  end
end

t = Time.now
#=> 2014-08-15 15:42:39 +0200

t.to_i
#=> 1408110159

t.to_pst
#=> Fri, 15 Aug 2014 06:42:39 PDT -07:00

t.to_pst.to_i
#=> 1408110159

# timestamp does not change!
```

Additionally you might also want the time extensions on `Numeric` and `Date`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date'
require 'active_support/core_ext/numeric/time'

2.days.from_now
#=> 2014-08-17 15:42:39 +0200
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This works. It'll also help in the future whenever I need some Rails functionality in my Sinatra project.

Comment: I also added some more extensions you might find useful.

Comment: Note that the gem (if you need it, I'm in a docker container so I have to explicitly include everything) is called 'activesupport', not 'active_support'

Answer (score 21):

In Pure Ruby

```
Time.now.utc.localtime("+05:30")
```

where +05:30 (IST) is the offset of the particular zone

Comment: Amazing!! After searching so many answers - this was the only perfect answer for me...

Comment: There's a problem with that. I ran this code `Time.new(1942).utc.localtime('+05:30')`, one on my local machine (my tz is Asia/Kolkata), and one on a server located in +0100 tz (https://rextester.com/l/ruby_online_compiler), the time returned is 15 hours 30 minutes advanced on my system even though I kept the timezone intact! I would like you to take a look at the timezone in 1942, it's +0630: ```>> Time.new(1942).zone
# => "+0630"
``` even when I am in +05:30...

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to load a ton of libraries, and if you don't mind doing it the poor man's way, and you know your offset is -8 for example, you can subtract 8*3600 seconds to get the new time.  For example,

```
offset=-8
t = Time.now + offset * 3600
```

You'll need to adjust for day light savings time yourself though, also this doesn't change the time zone so %z won't be right.

Comment: i was having issues trying to import activerecord time libs and dont really wanted to simply import all - i have a cloud app so the less is more... this is a good choice in these cases

Answer (score 2):

I recently did the same thing on an iron.io worker which default time is UTC

```
# For generality/testing, only require what you need. 
require 'active_support/all'  

# Set the Timezone 
Time.zone = "Asia/Hong_Kong" 

t = Time.zone.now
#=> 2015-01-20 16:44:58 +0800
```

For info on the supported Timezones take a look at ActiveSupport
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the current time in utc, then add the offset:

```
Time.now.utc + Time.zone_offset('PDT')
#=> 2015-12-01 18:10:07 UTC
```

The problem here is that `PDT` is fixed to `-8`, `PST` is fixed to `-7` and Pacific Zone (one that adjusts between the two based on time of year and daylight savings) does not exist, for that you likely need ActiveSupport.