# Getting timezone in pure Ruby (no rails)

Tags: ruby, tzinfo

I am wondering if I can change the timezone in Ruby. I am currently in Asia/Kolkata (+0530).

In my system if I run:

```
>> puts (1935..1945).map { |x| "#{x} => #{Time.new(x).strftime('%z')}" }
1935 => +0530
1936 => +0530
1937 => +0530
1938 => +0530
1939 => +0530
1940 => +0530
1941 => +0530
1942 => +0630
1943 => +0630
1944 => +0630
1945 => +0630
```

As you can see timezone changes based on historical events.

I want Ruby (running on any server in any place) to show the timzeone +0630 when Asia/Kolkata or IST is set.

---

But if I run this code on a [different system](https://rextester.com/SANH24233) located at different part of the globe:

I get back:

```
1935 => +0100
1936 => +0100
1937 => +0100
1938 => +0100
1939 => +0100
1940 => +0100
1941 => +0200
1942 => +0200
1943 => +0100
1944 => +0100
1945 => +0100
```

Which is probably correct according to their timezone.

Now if I try to follow this question [Change Time zone in pure ruby (not rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318222/change-time-zone-in-pure-ruby-not-rails/32833545), and the answer:

```
p Time.new(1942).utc.localtime("+05:30").strftime('%z')
=> "+0530"
```

My requirement breaks. Because Asia/Kolkata isn't +05:30 during 1942.

---

If I mention IST:

```
p Time.new(1942).utc.+(Time.zone_offset('IST')).strftime('%z')
=> "+0000"
```

This returns "+0000". But my desired output is "+0630".

---

Now there are [websites](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=19420909T173000&p1=54) which let you do that. So it's technically not impossible to get the +0630 on any server if I enter "IST".

---

So is there a way to getting back the timezone in Ruby by mentioning the timezone (IST)?

Comment: For the time being, this works ```TZ=Asia/Kolkata ruby -e "p Time.new(1942).strftime('%z')"```

Comment: There's nothing you can do about historical changes to the "Asia/Kolkata" time zone. If you're seeing offsets that are wrong for a given date, you'll either need to update your tzdata or handle it yourself in your Ruby or database code. However, you can certainly create Time and DateTime objects that use the zone or a specific offset for a given date. You can also temporarily set `ENV["TZ"]` in Ruby or `TZ` in shell commands.

Comment: the [DateTime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) gem is generally better at handling historical dates. The default `Time` is only built to work with relatively recent times for which the modern times standards apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the time being, this works `TZ=Asia/Kolkata ruby -e "p Time.new(1942).strftime('%z')"`

Setting the `TZ` environment variable also works from within Ruby: (seen in [`test_time_tz.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/440ab313d0a6b0eb98195dc0b8aa618844d97287/test/ruby/test_time_tz.rb#L19-L27))

```
def with_tz(tz)
  old = ENV['TZ']
  ENV['TZ'] = tz
  yield
ensure
  ENV['TZ'] = old
end

with_tz('Asia/Kolkata') do
  (1935..1945).each do |x|
    puts "#{x} => #{Time.local(x).strftime('%z')}"
  end
end
```